# Multiple table JOINS and conditions

Tags: mysql, join

From the following tables I need to retrieve messages for a particular `recipientID` provided the `senderID` is found in `users` table and `postID` is either 20 or NULL in the `messages` table.

I cannot use two or more separate queries since I need `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` applied for pagination.

`messages` table:

```
--------------
ID | messageType | recipientID | senderID | postID (optional)
-------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1           | 100         | 1        | 20
2  | 2           | 100         | 2        | NULL
3  | 3           | 100         | 2        | 40
4  | 3           | 100         | 5        | 75
5  | 2           | 100         | 7        | 20
```

`users` table:

```
---
ID
---
1
2
```

`posts` table:

```
---------------
ID | postStatus
---------------
20  | published
40  | draft
```

The required result:

```
messages.ID | messages.messageType
----------------------------------
1           | 1
2           | 2
```

To start somewhere I began with the query below. But I'm stuck on how to modify it to give me the desired results.

```
    SELECT messages.ID, 
           messages.messageType 
      FROM messages
RIGHT JOIN users 
        ON messages.senderID = users.ID
RIGHT JOIN posts 
        ON messages.postID = posts.ID
     WHERE messages.recipientID = 100
      DESC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 1
```

If possible I'd like to avoid a sub-query.

I am also open to structure changes of my current table design.

Comment: `and postID "if specified (not null)"` Would this not mean the messageID 2 should not be on your result set?

Comment: Nope, I would need messageID 2 returned as shown in the expected result table.

Comment: Then you have to fix your requirements.

Comment: Agree with @Prix as `posts.ID` cannot be null in the Posts table

Comment: Can I modify the Messages table structure for desired result or are there other solutions to the problem at hand? I'm open to suggestions here.

Comment: @Prix I can substitute NULL with "0". BTW, 3,3 anyways should not make it into the result set since the postStatus is "draft".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving your result set must include the `NULL` row, you could try this:

```
   SELECT m.ID, 
          m.messageType
     FROM messages m
     JOIN users u
       ON m.senderID = u.ID
LEFT JOIN posts p
       ON m.postID = p.ID
    WHERE m.recipientID = 100 AND (m.postID = 20 OR m.postID IS NULL)
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e770c/3)

```
   SELECT m.ID, 
          m.messageType
     FROM messages m
     JOIN users u
       ON m.senderID = u.ID
LEFT JOIN posts p
       ON m.postID = p.ID
    WHERE m.recipientID = 100 AND (m.postID IS NULL OR p.postStatus = 'published')
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e770c/4)

I don't think there is a way to dynamically include the `postStatus` without directly point the ones you want since you have multiple status and you want 2 specific ones.

The main issue with your `postStatus` is the fact you can have multiple entries that are valid and have multiple status aside from `published` and `NULL` alone.

Comment: The postID is hardcoded into the query. postID is not known to me beforehand. I'm only aware of the recipientID. Though my question says I'd like to avoid a subquery. Is this possible if at all with a subquery?

Comment: @John the post ID is unknown but the "published" is known to you correct? See second example. I don't think there is any other way using `JOIN`s but perhaps a more experienced user know of a way using `JOIN`s.

Comment: It appears you've nailed it with the second solution. Though I'd still need to create few test cases to consider this resolved. I'll keep you posted. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @John just make sure to check it as the accepted answer if that solves your issue :) after you tried it.

Comment: Accepting the answer. It works on all test cases. I'd suggest you explain the second solution in a bit more detail for a better understanding. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @John The only difference is that the second query uses the `postStatus` column rather than the `id` of post with the hard coded 'published' that is what you were aware of. But if there is something specific you are having doubts/question with on the query feel free to ask.